# How do you make an iOS app launch a captive portal (hotspot login)?

Tags: iphone, ios, reachability

When using Safari at a place with a captive portal like Starbucks, iOS devices will launch a special modal webview to authenticate with the portal. I've seen third party apps trigger this so it's possible to do outside of Safari but I don't know how. It doesn't seem to come for free just by using Reachability or making a network request.

Edit:
The best I can say is the answer I accepted works sometimes. It's probably the right answer but I don't know why it's not consistent. It can take several network attempts before it will launch the captive portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [`UIRequiresPersistentWiFi`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12) set in your plist file?  That is the only public API available to devs to indicate WiFi need.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a shot. I finally found Apple's docs on this key. They really bury it. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW4 .

Comment: The link provided above is broken: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW12